# Copy Columns from one sheet to another using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy column from one sheet to another of different workbooks. This is my code for copying:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range
    Set sourceColumn = wb.Worksheets(cmb).Columns(Form.ComboBox2.Value)
    Set targetColumn = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns("PART NUMBER")
    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End Sub
```

`cmb` is a global variable. I'm getting a `Run Time Error 13: Type Mismatch` at `Set sourceColumn = wb.Worksheets(cmb).Columns(Form.ComboBox2.Value)`

Can someone please point out whats going on and how this is to be fixed?

Whole Code:

```
Public wb As Workbook
Public cmb As String

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim Cell As Range, rng As Range, sht As Worksheet
    cmb = Form.ComboBox1.Value
    Set sht = wb.Worksheets(cmb)
    'assuming your headers are always on the first row...
    Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Range("A1"), _
                        sht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))

    'add some code here to clear the lists first!...
    For Each Cell In rng.Cells
        If Len(Cell.Value) > 0 Then
            Form.ComboBox2.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox3.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox4.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox5.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox6.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox7.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox8.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox9.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox10.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox11.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox12.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox13.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sFilePath As String
    sFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
    For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
          Form.ComboBox1.AddItem sht.Name
    Next sht
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range
    Set sourceColumn = wb.Worksheets(cmb).Columns(Form.ComboBox2.Value)
    Set targetColumn = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns("PART NUMBER")
    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End Sub
```

Comment: Write `debug.print Form.ComboBox2.Value` on the line before the error. What do you get in the immediate window?

Comment: It prints "PART NUMBER", which is the selected `Form.ComboBox2.Value`

Comment: See the answer, it should be either a `string` with the name of the column(s) or the number of the column.

Comment: @Vityata: PART NUMBER is the column header. How do I copy using the column header?

Comment: You should locate the column with `PART NUMBER`. There are a few ways to do it, `WorksheetFunction.Match` is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not passing the correct value as a parameter in Columns(). If you use the macro recorder, you will see that the parameter for Columns looks like this:

`"E:G"` in a simple macro as `Columns("E:G").Select`. Or a number as `Columns(5).Select`.

Try a really simple fix, changing the line with the error to the following:

`Set sourceColumn = wb.Worksheets(cmb).Columns("A:D")` If it works, then try to remake the code.

Comment: I want to copy by the column header names.

Comment: @user248884 - your approach should be a bit different - you have to locate the column with this specific header and then you should copy it, by refering its number as a parameter to `Columns()`. Try with `WorksheetFunction.Match("PART NUMBER",rows(1))`. It would give you the column number. This is what you should give as a parameter.